# Вывод непонятных символы в си

Tags: c

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать функцию по поразрядному сложению двух длинных чисел. При запуске выводятся непонятные символы. Код ниже и он тестовый, первое число всегда будет больше второго. Буду рад, если кто то поможет

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int findDigitsCount(long num){
    int digits_count = 0;
    while(num>0){
        num /=10;
        digits_count++;
    }
    return digits_count;
}

int findMax(int num1, int num2){
    if(num1 >= num2){
        return num1;
    }
    else{
        return num2;
    }
}

char * additionNumbers(char * num1, char * num2, int digits_count1, int digits_count2){
    int max_digits_count = findMax(digits_count1, digits_count2);
    int remainder = 0;
    if(max_digits_count==digits_count1){
        for(int i = max_digits_count; i!=0; i--){
            num1[i] = ((num1[i] - '0') + (num2[i] - '0') + remainder) + '0';
            remainder = num1[i] / 10;
            num1[i] %= 10;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    long num1, num2;
    printf("Input first num: ");
    scanf("%ld", &num1);
    printf("Input second num: ");
    scanf("%ld", &num2);
    int digits_count1 = findDigitsCount(num1);
    char * char_num1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (digits_count1+1));
    sprintf(char_num1, "%ld", num1);
    int digits_count2 = findDigitsCount(num1);
    char * char_num2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (digits_count2+1));
    sprintf(char_num2, "%ld", num2);
    additionNumbers(char_num1, char_num2, digits_count1, digits_count2);
    printf("%s", char_num1);
    free(char_num1);    
    free(char_num2);
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: А "Input first num: " не выводится при запуске?

Comment: Вводы переменных и преобразование чисел в строки sprintf работает

Comment: Слишком рано преобразуете число обратно в символ: `... + '0'`. Сейчас остаток и целая часть берутся от _ASCII-кода_ символа. Причём символ не обязательно цифра, если сумма `(num1[i] - '0') + (num2[i] - '0') + remainder` больше девяти.

Comment: А как это можно сделать тогда ? Даже если убрать ... + '0', то всё равно выводятся непонятные символы

Answer (score 0):

Для начала:

1. У вас функция *findDigitsCount(num1)* вызывается два раза с одним и тем же аргументом *num1*. А *num2* вообще не используется.
2. В функции *additionNumbers()* есть оператор *if(max_digits_count==digits_count1){* но в нём нет ветки *else*. Что должно происходить, если равенства нет?
3. Функция char * additionNumbers объявлена, как возвращающая указатель. Но в ней нет ни одного оператора *return*.
4. В этой же функции есть оператор *remainder = num1[i] / 10;* Проблема в том, в *num1[i]* хранится **код символа**. Делить его на **число** 10 абсолютно бессмыслленно.